# Problem when routing from outside a project to internal route automatically head to index.php

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, routes, php-language-server

I have a project which I have to share external routes from it like so ..
ex: https://www.example.com/something

If I head to the root website it does not cause any problem and if I head to any internal route no problem causes.
The problem starts when I take a copy of a given route site inside the website and paste it to address bar or share a link to any resource when I enter the route the website automatically redirects to https://www.example.com/index.php and this causes a problem with some integration callbacks because it invalid it.

I think it's a problem with htaccess but I cannot identify the problem because I have a lack in experience with htaccess rules and how to manage it with server configs.

1. I tried to change the rewrite rules in htaccess but no result
   success
2. I tried to find a config file inside the server that override none
   to make it accept overriding but no result success also

This is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{ REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L, R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php[L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule.* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```